# xsl transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have this bxf file. I need to apply an xsl transform to it:

```
<AAA>
<BBB:Name lang="ABC">Some text</BBB:Name>
 </AAA>
```

Here is my xsl transform:

```
 <test>
     <xsl:value-of select="bxf:AAA/bxf:BBB:Name[@lang = 'ABC']"/>                
 </test>
```

Am I doing this correct. After doing it in this way, my xsl is not being parsed properly.

**Edit:**

It says: Expected end of the expression, found ':'.

**Output**

```
<test>
Some text
</test>
```

Comment: Please post your desired output...

Comment: @SundarG : I have edited to include that. Thanks bro. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: It seems you are lookin for correct XPATH which is: bxf:AAA/BBB:Name[@lang = 'ABC']"

Comment: Thanks Navin, But why is it giving me an error then: Expected end of the expression, found ':'.

Comment: You're getting that error because `bxf:BBB:Name` is not valid syntax. A node name can have at most one colon in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part causing the error is this portion of the path:

```
bxf:BBB:Name
```

That's not a valid node name.  Try using this (you will also need to ensure that the `BBB:` namespace prefix is declared in your XSLT):

```
<test>
     <xsl:value-of select="bxf:AAA/BBB:Name[@lang = 'ABC']"/>                
</test>
```